# What's the difference between dotnet build and build from inside Visual Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I have an MVC project and I'm going through some Microsoft Virtual Academy videos. I noticed that my project builds fine from Visual Studio but not from a dotnet build command. What's the difference? The error says something about my project configuration being bad. I have .NET Core SDK 1.0.4 and Visual Studio 2015 Community.
[image]

[image]

These builds were done one right after the other. No changes were made to my solution in between.

Comment: Hard to guess what the "MCD" platform could possibly be.  Well, dotnet doesn't know either so keels over.  Just delete it to get ahead.

Comment: The IDE executes `dotnet restore` in the background. BTW, use VS2017 for .NET Core please.